# Why is the release timestamp not changing when assets are updated?

Tags: github, github-actions, release

I have an application that I [develop and share](https://github.com/wsw70/syncthing-map) via GitHub.

I automated the build of binaries via [Actions](https://github.com/wsw70/syncthing-map/blob/master/.github/workflows/stable.yaml)

```yaml
name: build stable version
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  release-linux-amd64:
    name: release linux/amd64
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: wangyoucao577/go-release-action@v1.34
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.REPO_TOKEN }}
          goos: linux
          goarch: amd64
          compress_assets: OFF
          overwrite: TRUE
  release-windows-amd64:
    name: release linux/amd64
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: wangyoucao577/go-release-action@v1.34
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.REPO_TOKEN }}
          goos: windows
          goarch: amd64
          compress_assets: OFF
          overwrite: TRUE
```

I have two releases, `stable version` and `development`, which are updated with relevant binaries upon a push of the branch `master` or `dev`, respectively.

This works fine.

As you can [see](https://github.com/wsw70/syncthing-map/releases/tag/master), the binaries were updated a few minutes ago, but the release timestamp points to two days ago, when I created that release:

[image]

**Why isn't that timestamp updated with the updates of the binaries, and how to make it be synchronized with them?**

Comment: This workflow run (https://github.com/wsw70/syncthing-map/actions/runs/3904362940) pushed the binaries to release assets.

Comment: Also, the names of both jobs are the same. You might want to change the second one to `windows/amd64`.

Comment: Your [workflow configuration](https://github.com/wsw70/syncthing-map/actions/runs/3904362940/workflow) is supposed to run to commits to the `main` branch so that's what it's doing. If you need to push binaries only on release then configure it accordingly as in this example (https://github.com/wangyoucao577/go-release-action#basic-example). Observe the `on:` configuration.

Comment: Usually, for commits and PRs, you want to push the binaries to workflow artifacts, And, for releases, the binaries would go to release artifacts as well. So, you need to configure for both the cases. Here's an example that only pushes artifacts to release on tagged/releases: https://github.com/iamazeem/spancopy/blob/bf4503bd6492aecfed398b7f51c235d85a9b7a2f/.github/workflows/ci.yml#L203-L211.

Comment: @Azeem: sorry but I do not understnd. Why is the timestamp different? (the binaries are where I expected them to land, this is not the problem)

Comment: Oh, right. So, you do want to push those binaries to release assets. Well, the release date is when you created it. With your current workflow, each new commit will push the newly generated binaries to release assets. So, you'll see the updated timestamps of binaries with each successful workflow run.

Comment: This action (https://github.com/wangyoucao577/go-release-action) builds and pushes binaries to release artifacts. It doesn't create a new release. I believe you expected it to do both or update the release itself too along with new binaries, right?

Comment: You'd better read existing discussions first, as GitHub internals matter a lot in such situations and you cannot bend the behavior anyway you like, https://github.com/community/community/discussions/5447#discussioncomment-1555826 and you can always find workarounds (like putting the timestamp you want in releases notes section) as this is not the end of the world.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to have an Action that does the work

```yaml
name: create release on tag

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - "v*"

jobs:
  build_release:
    name: build_release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - uses: actions/setup-go@v3
        with:
          go-version-file: "go.mod"
      - name: build
        run: go build -o sayhello .

      - name: release
        uses: softprops/action-gh-release@v1
        with:
          files: sayhello
          generate_release_notes: true
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.REPO_TOKEN }}
```

The routine is to commit and push as usual, and when you decide to create a release you tag it (with a tag stating with `v`) and push the tag to GitHub.

This will trigger the action and create a release with the selected binaries. Source code will also be in the assets, I do not know how to make it so that they are not added (but this is a detail).